# How to make Scroll Rect to not slide on start in Unity

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

It is allways keeping slide to a middle somewhere on start, even though a slider set to zero. And even though I unlink a scrollbar from a scroll rect.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Maybe show any code you used? heirarchy? picture of the inspector?

Comment: Try to learn about the scrollrect in [this video](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-scroll-rect)

Comment: I did already. It doesn't answer. I can create a brand new scroll view UI element and on start it slides at the end.

Comment: Where is the Content of the scrollrect is located? Make sure its in the bounds the scrollrect

Comment: It is! It still not working

Comment: Try to change the Movement type from Elastic to Clamped.